# how to remove a https redirection for only one .php file in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the https redirection for my web page only for one .php file. I found this but I don't know how to set my .php direction. Thanks in advance

.php file = [www.myhost.com/myphp.php](http://www.myhost.com/myphp.php)

```
# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /commerce_paypal/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The above code won't work. No browser will follow a redirection from https to http. This will _always_ result in a huge and massive warning. For very good reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your condition reversed. You need to use this:

```
# force https:// to all but selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+myfile\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// to selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+myfile\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: None of the common browsers will accept a redirection from https to http. This is technically correct, and a redirection will get sent. But it won't get followed.

Comment: IMO `https -> http` rule won't be even required if first one is correctly excluding desired URLs.